# Install PHP modules on CentOS

Tags: php, module, centos, php-5.5, centos7

I'm trying to install PHP 5.5.21 on CentOS 7.0.
When I execute `php -v`
I get about 10 modules errors like this one:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: curl: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
```

I tryed to install or update package with `pecl install curl` and `pecl upgrade curl`
But pecl always responds :

```
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/curl"
```

And `yum install php-curl` says:

```
Package php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

How can I do to fix modules error?

Comment: just because the rpm package is installed doesn't mean it's activated in php. check php.ini and whatever other .ini files might exist in /etc/php5 or whatever it is in your centos install. And from your error message, you've installed the incorrect version. Your PHP is 2 years newer than the curl you've installed.

Comment: `yum install php-curl` should not output a message about `php-common`. Are you sure that's what is happening?

Comment: Yes, I confirm that I have curl.so in my modules directory. I also have a `/etc/php.d/curl.ini` which contains `extension="curl.so"` and php.ini is configured to include `/etc/php.d/*.ini`

Comment: Yes I confirm that when I try to install `php-curl`, I get a message about `php-common` beceause lots of modules are included in the `php-common` package.

Answer (score 1):

Try running: `find / -name curl.so`

Then copy the directory it finds `curl.so` in and create a symbolic link to it where the rest of your working .so files are stored:

```
cd <where your working .so files are>
ln -s <where curl.so is> curl.so
```

Then edit your `php.ini` file and enable the extension:

```
extension=curl.so
```

Restart apache:

```
service httpd restart
service apache2 restart `#If the service is named apache2 rather than httpd`
```

This resolved my problem when I had a similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved my problem removing the custom PHP installation and using [this tutorial](https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/) to install PHP 5.5